# get id and echo in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i have this link floors.php?id=building1&floor1

it is showing like this

flats.php?id=Building1&1

building name and floor no

link have floor no and building name

now how can i connect in MySQL query

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM floors where buildingname='$id' And 
floorno='i want here floor no how can i do this' ORDER BY floorno
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your url should be like,

```
 floors.php?id=1&floorno=5
```

In php file,

You can use,

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); //output =1. 

$floorno = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['floorno']); // output=5 

$query = "SELECT * FROM floors where buildingname='".$id."' and floorno='".$floorno."' ORDER BY floorno
```

You may use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

mysqli_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysqli_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a

**Note:** mysql_* deprecated Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore!